# Bidirectional Reference/Label Commands

Tags: cross-referencing

I've written a *synopsis section* for each chapter of my thesis, and I'd like to refer to various sections or subsections using `\label` and `\ref` commands. However, since the synopsis precedes the chapter, I'm getting errors simply because the relevant `\ref` commands precede the `\label` commands.

Is there a simple work-around to allow for bidirectional referencing?

Thanks!

Comment: This shouldn't cause errors, so you must be doing something else. Can you provide a minimal example of what doesn't work. (You need to run latex at least twice to resolve the references; I'm assuming you're doing that?)

Comment: Correct! I had to run in 4 times to take. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be no problem with forward references. However, it may take a number of `latex` runs to resolve all of the references. Usually two runs is sufficient, but more are sometimes necessary.